# Spliting a polyline object by line ID based on @data values

Tags: raster, r, leaflet, line, sp

I am trying split a `SpatialLinesDataFrame` by attributes I merged into `@data`

I extracted a list of line ID's associated with a points data frame and aggregated them by category and line ID in `dplyr`

```
# A tibble: 1,430 x 3
# Groups:   Crime type [14]
   `Crime type`          nearest_line_id                          n
   <chr>                 <fct>                                <int>
 1 Anti-social behaviour 00206205-7878-4F17-BFF3-6086683F041B     1
 2 Anti-social behaviour 00937739-39C7-47E6-888A-4890FA2D47D8     1
 3 Anti-social behaviour 0108B4DD-049A-4A1D-A7CD-8F216AA0DB06     1
 4 Anti-social behaviour 018FB4F0-2DB1-48C4-A627-52A358B99E34     1
 5 Anti-social behaviour 025D1F38-C552-4D84-AC0D-6A1178C10B0F     1
 6 Anti-social behaviour 04542A56-3E24-4F25-AA64-CA874E7E3B5E     1
 7 Anti-social behaviour 04ACF5BC-78A0-475A-9294-F878E53A8625     1
 8 Anti-social behaviour 04AE68AE-E0A9-42B2-908E-29F4EC92051D     1
 9 Anti-social behaviour 05068729-E1D9-4AC6-86BA-06B126395516     1
10 Anti-social behaviour 06E16FFC-F03D-46D3-89A2-E20DDB19DA1C     1
```

I then merged this dataframe into the `@data`attribute of my `SpatialLinesDataFrame`

```
Clipped_Street_2@data<-sp::merge(Clipped_Street_2@data,Points_agg,by.x="identifier",by.y="nearest_line_id", all=TRUE )
```

Now I want to split `SpatialLinesDataFrame` by the `Crime type` column so that I can use it in `leaflet` map control function using the following script.

```
map<-leaflet(Clipped_Street_2) %>%addTiles()

names(Clipped_Street_2) %>%
  purrr::walk( function(df) {
        map <<- map %>%
      addCircles(data=Clipped_Street_2[[df]],
                 lng=~Longitude , 
                 lat=~Latitude,
                 weight=~n,
                 label=~df,
                 color = ~pal(`Crime type`),
                 group = ~df)
  })

%>%
  addLayersControl(
    overlayGroups = names(Clipped_Street_2),
    options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE))
```

My problem is the splitting doesn't appear to work. It does for simple point data sets and I was wondering if there is a function, method or tool I am missing to split this dataset. I am currently working with a simple split function but I get an error (see below).

```
Clipped_Street_2 <- split(Clipped_Street_2@data, Clipped_Street_2@data$`Crime type`)

Error in split.default(x = seq_len(nrow(x)), f = f, drop = drop, ...) : 
  group length is 0 but data length > 0
```

Not really sure what to do next, but I will post any progress I make myself. [This solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/218197/i-want-to-do-spatiallines-programatically) seemed sensible, but I couldn't make it work in my situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via an index in a for loop or `lapply`. For simplicity's sake I will show a for loop.

```
street2 <- list() 
  for(i in unique(Clipped_Street$Crime type)) {
    street2[[i]] <- street[street$Crime type == i,] 
 }
```

This will result in the same type of output as split, a list with a SpatialLinesDataFrame, representing the subset attribute, for each list element.

Comment: Thanks @jeffrey-evans I will toy around with the loop!

Comment: I can split the dataframe as a flat dataframe. However, that creates a new problem of associating the spatial lines back in to a split dataframe. Otherwise, trying to split a spatial lines data frame I get the following error `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object not a >= 2-column array`